# Why are Google Maps not using direct manipulation? Should I?

Tags: interaction-design, maps, radial-menu, direct-manipulation

I am building a [map-like interface](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/54672/labels-in-a-zoomable-interface) and there will be several actions user will be able to perform on objects. For clarity lets assume I want to click on point A and select an action to navigate to point B - like in Google Maps.

I was planing to use a radial navigation that you guys [praised for speed and usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/54677/name-the-on-click-menu-in-circle-around-object-interface) and if I am right radial menu that pops up around selected object can be regarded as [direct manipulation interface](http://goodui.org/#19).

But Google is not using direct manipulation in it's latest redesign of it's map app - neither on desktop nor on touch devices.

[image]

I assume there are situations when classic unassociated menu is better than direct manipulation. Why did Google decide the way it did? How do I decide? Should I copy Google for the sake of familiarity or should I use radial menu around selected object to embrace direct manipulation?

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly with Google Maps there are two routes to a location

- search box
- browse map

If an location information is always displayed same place regardless of the route used to find it this is a UX win in terms of Consistency heuristic.

Secondly note that in Google maps the linear menu changes. This means that a radial menu would alter. And thus any benefit of ["consistency [that] allows users to create a more efficient muscle memory."](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/04/fittss-law-and-user-experience/) is lost.

Thirdly basing a location's UI around search box enables

- efficient navigation from search box
- clutter free exploration around point of interest
- more real estate for white space and extended services
- seamlessly hold current marker location even during zoom, pan
- Large UI block not far from centre of map (deafult POI location) is reasonably efficient wrt Fitts law

Should you have radial menu?  If you have no search, a uniform menu that does not use extensive real estate and no risk about clutter around POI then yes.

Comment: Thanks, that's a perfect answer. I will undoubtedly need a search box in my map too so I am thinking of following the Google Map path.