# Multi position switch (while avoiding dropdowns and skeuomorphism)

Tags: gui-design, dropdown, multi-selection, radio-buttons, maps

I have a very visual, map-like interface where most of the interaction takes place in navigation cards as opposite to [direct manipulation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/why-are-google-maps-not-using-direct-manipulation-should-i).

[image]

I need to add a "dimension selector" to each node that will change the organisation of the data. I want to put emphasis on the fact that there are other dimension to switch between in the first place (there will be between 1 and 5 dimensions). What are my options?

Up until now all nodes in the graph had the same functionality so it was not a problem to put it into the navigation tabs that open when you select any of the nodes but this one can be different for each node and that is why I would like to put visual clue directly into the graph.

What options do I have with multi-position switchers with limited number of options? Radio buttons? Or this?

[image]

PS: I would like to avoid skeuomorphism.

PPS: you can see the tool I am building [here](http://wikibudgets.org/sankey/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using a dropdown menu?

Anyway, I would use colors and an icon to indicate what the current budget is, in the place of where currently the blue text says "budget". With the default being set to just "budget", and offering up alternatives like savings account, government grants, sales income. Example:

[image]

Functionally it'd work like a radio button, but it wouldn feel like one, and it would be quite obvious (or at least I think it'd be) that it can be changed.

Comment: you should shade (make pale) the "unselected" options at least slightly. The text itself does not really deliver the message of being selected, at least to me.